# How to throw an exception inside a while loop when fetching mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using mysqli prepared statements in an OOP manner. Everything is working as intended, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to detect and then throw an exception during a while loop. This how my code stands at the moment and it works perfectly.

```
$rslt=array();
$data=array();
$stmt->bind_result($rslt['col1'], $rslt['col2'], $rslt['col3'], $rslt['col4']);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $data[]=$rslt;
}
```

However it contains no way of throwing an exception. This is how I throw an exception in a similar script which is limited to 1 result (therefore I don't need to loop through them on this example).

```
$rslt=array();
$data=array();
$stmt->bind_result($rslt['col1'], $rslt['col2'], $rslt['col3'], $rslt['col4']);
if(!$stmt->fetch()){
   throw new Exception('Failed to fetch results', 1);
}
$data[]=$rslt;
```

I'm almost trying to do what is in the code below but it throws the following error:-

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW in xxx/xxx/includes/_xxxClass.php on line 95

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $data[]=$rslt or throw new Exception('Failed to fetch results', 1);
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to see if there is an error with fetching the results and then throw an exception inside my while loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *doesn't work*?

Comment: Are you referring to code block #3? I get a PHP error telling me that what I have done contains invalid syntax. Should this be correct?

Comment: Sure, one second, I'll run it again. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW in xxx/xxx/includes/_xxxClass.php on line 95". Line 95 contains this code "$data[]=$rslt or throw new Exception('Failed to fetch results', 1);".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test you are performing is flawed. [`mysqli::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns false on failure, so your while loop will exit as soon as it sees false. If no results are returned, then the loop will not execute and $data will be empty.

What you need to do instead is test if $data is populated after the while loop and then throw your exception if it is empty:-

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $data[]=$rslt;
}
if(empty($data)) throw new Exception('Failed to fetch results', 1);
```

On reflection, you shouldn't be throwing an exception just because no results are returned, just return the empty array:-

Exceptions are for handling exceptional circumstances and an empty result set is not exceptional.

Comment: I'm using Mysqli prepared statements, not PDO. But according to the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php the method fetch() also returns FALSE on failure. So theoretically I could apply the same logic as you mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but yes, the same logic applies.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. This is a better alternative to checking during each loop of my while() statement if an error has occurred. Surely this must be better on resources aswell?

Comment: Sorry, I would upvote you but it requires a reputation of 15 :( Marked you as accepted answer though

Answer (score 0):

Considering `$mysqli` your mysqli handler you can try with:

```
if ($mysqli->errno) { // an error occurred, throw exception }
```

Comment: Would I use this inside my while loop or before it? An example would be ideal, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so this would be a correct use of that if statement? http://pastebin.com/1nRqTGSq

Comment: Just noticed I missed a semi-colon on line 3, assume that will be fixed for deployment!